# How to write json data in html file in python

Tags: python, django

I have this json data `{'latest_question_list': ((1, "What's up?", datetime.datetime(2019, 4, 19, 7, 38, 6, 449735)),)}` , i want to show this data in my html file can anyone please help me how to show this data in it, here is my whole code added, can anyone please help me to resolve this issue, also i need help why i am getting database result in tuple ?

models.py

```
import datetime
from django.utils import timezone
from django.db import connection
from django.db import models


class Question():
    @classmethod
    def get_poll_question(cls):
        with connection.cursor() as cursor:
            db_table = "polls_question"
            cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM '+db_table)
            allquestion = cursor.fetchall()
            return allquestion

class Choice():
    def get_options(cls):
        with connection.cursor() as cursor:
            db_table = "polls_choice"
            cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM "+ db_table+" WHERE question_id = '1' ")
            choice_text = cursor.fetchall();
            return choice_text
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render

# Create your views here.


from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.template import loader
from .models import Choice, Question
from django.urls import reverse
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render



def index(request):
    latest_question_list = Question.get_poll_question()
    context = {'latest_question_list': latest_question_list}
    print(context)
    return render(request, 'polls/index.html', context)
```

index.html

```
{% load static %}

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'polls/style.css' %}">

{% if latest_question_list %}
    <ul>
    {% for question in latest_question_list %}
        <li><a href="">{{ question.question_text }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% else %}
    <p>No polls are available.</p>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: i think your json data is not standard ! can you change that or it should be just like that ?

Comment: it is not a json, it has python tuple

Comment: @shourav how to conver tuple in associate array ?

Comment: can you update the question with the definition of `Question.get_poll_question()`?

Comment: Sure let me update

Comment: question updated

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use the double brackets {{}} in the html, like this:

```
{{ latest_question_list }}
```